# Significant numbers - arithmetic average of proper divisors is not bigger than root of that number

Tags: java, algorithm

The task seems pretty easy - on input I get number of tests (`numOfTests`), then two numbers (`downBorder`, `upBorder`) and I have to find how many numbers between those numbers (`downBorder`, `upBorder`) are significant numbers where significant number is a number which arithmetic average of proper divisors(all divisors except one and the same number) are smaller or equal than square root of that number.
I wrote the code and probably it works however it's too slow.
My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //faster than Scanner
        int numOfTests = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfTests; i++)
        {
            String[] borders = bf.readLine().split(" ");
            long downBorder = Long.parseLong(borders[0]);
            long upBorder = Long.parseLong(borders[1]);
            //System.out.println(String.format("down:  %s, up: %s", downBorder, upBorder));
            System.out.println(countNumberOfSignificantNumbers(downBorder, upBorder));
        }
    }

    /**
     * print numbers of significant numbers - (arithmetic average of all divisors that is not bigger than root of that number)
     * e.g 4 is significant but 6 is not
     * @param downBorder
     * @param upBorder
     */
    private static int countNumberOfSignificantNumbers(Long downBorder, Long upBorder) {
        int numberOfSignificantNumbers = 0;
        for(Long i = downBorder; i <= upBorder; i++)
        {
            if(i%2 != 0)
                continue;
            else
            {
                double avgOfProperDivisors = getAvgArithOfSumOfNumberDividers(i);
                if(avgOfProperDivisors != 0 && avgOfProperDivisors <= Math.sqrt(i))
                    numberOfSignificantNumbers++;
            }
        }
        return numberOfSignificantNumbers;
    }

    /**
     * method returns the arithemtic average of all proper divisors (all divisors except one and number itself)
     * @param number
     * @return
     */
    public static double getAvgArithOfSumOfNumberDividers(Long number)
    {
        long maxD = number/2;
        long sum=0;
        long numOfDivs = 0;
        for(long i = 2; i <= maxD; i++)
        {
            if(number % i == 0)
            {
                numOfDivs++;
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return (numOfDivs > 0) ? (double)sum/numOfDivs : 0;
    }
}
```

The bottleneck in this task is counting average of divisors. How can I make it better and faster?

```
Example input:
2
4 6
1 3

Example output:
1
0
```

Comment: I don't see requirement for average of divisors. Where is exact formulation? What does example show?

Comment: I have to check if average of divisors are smaller or equal of root of that number and I count it in `getAvgArithOfSumOfNumberDividers()`. In my opinion that method is a problem. @MBo edited question to make it more clear

Comment: One point is that your code calls `getAvgArithOfSumOfNumberDividers` twice. Call it only once and store the result in a variable within `countNumberOfSignificantNumbers`

Comment: @ThomasKlager thanks, good advise! Edited post and tried the code but it still too slow.

Comment: `long maxD = number/2;` shouldn't you be square rooting it? (I'd actually formulate the loop guard as `i*i <= number`)

Comment: @AndyTurner For example `Math.square(6)` will be `2.45` and `3` is also a divisor of 6. Should I make a for loop to ceil of Math.square(number)?
When I make `i * i <= number` then for 6 I won't find `3` as divisor

Comment: @Michu93 oh, ofc. No, ceil wouldn't work because ceil(sqrt(10)) is 4, but it has 5 as a divisor. But you can at least halve the number of iterations, because if 6 is divisible by 2, then it's also divisible by (6/2). So you can count both at once.

Comment: @Andy eh, sure, `ceil` won't work ;/
I try to get what you mean in previous comment but have problem with that.
Generally, do you claim that `i * i <= number` will work?

Comment: @Michu93 no, it's a standard trick from simple testing of primes. It may not be applicable here.

Comment: @Andy, yes I seen it in eratosthenes sieve but it won't work in my example, I think.

Comment: @Michu93 what's the range of `downBorder ` and `upBorder `?

Comment: @Ishpreet `(1<=downBorder<=upBorder<=10^9)`

Comment: @Michu93 why the prime numbers are not included in the answer? Like according to the definition you provided, **prime numbers** will have 0 arithmetic average of proper divisors, so they should **significant numbers** too!

Comment: why are you discarding the uneven numbers? Isn't `9` a significant number by that definition?  Actually I believe 4 is the only even number that will be significant - significant number can have only one factor (I think) and every even number greater than 4 will have more than one factor.  (obviously I am disregarding any non-positive, despite not specified)

Comment: @Carlos
Yeah, `9` is significant, my checking was wrong.

Comment: well, @Ishpreet almost put my thinking as a reply [:-)

Comment: @Ishpreet From the beginning I wanted to look at exact problem statement but author keeps a secret :)

Comment: @MBo sorry but I really didn't "keep a secret", I didn't know the answer

Comment: @MBo Even I was also interested in exact problem :)

Comment: @Michu93 It seemed to me that you described own interpretation of the problem.  (Now you have included `average` into main text)

Comment: @MBo, I made a mistake in main text but it was all the time right in subject. Actually I edited the main text at 8.47 so it's nearly 15 mins before anyone posted an answer and no, it''s not my interpretation of the problem. The orginal text of task was exactly the same as I posted in question. Seems that author of that problem assumed that the programmer will figure it out by himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Significant Number will always be a perfect square of a prime number like 4, 9, 25, 49, 121 etc. All you need to check is how many perfect square of a prime numbers lie between `upBorder` and `downBorder`.

Comment: You are totally right! 4,9,16,25...
@Edit well, wait, 16 is not a significant number because `2+4+8/3=4.66` while `sqrt(16) = 4`

Comment: it would be more correct, IMHO, to say that the number can only have one proper divisor (factor), which also includes perfect squares (but not all)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the complexity of the loop from `O(number)` to `O(sqrt(number))`.

This is based on the observation that if `number` is divisible by `i`, then it is also divisible by `number/i`. Given this, you can count the two divisors at once; given that the sparsity of the divisors increases as the number increases (i.e. the number of numbers you have to check before finding a divisor), you can save a lot of work in this way.

For example:

```
    for (long i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
        // i is a divisor, so increment the counters.
        numOfDivs++; sum += i;

        long c = n / i;
        if (c != i) {
          // c is a distinct divisor from i, so also increment the counters.
          numOfDivs++; sum += c;
        }
      }
    }
```

For example, 10 = 5*2. This approach finds a divisor when i=2, meaning that c=5. It can stop checking after i=3. In contrast, checking while `i<=10/2` will stop checking after i=5.

As the number increases, the difference becomes far greater. For example, with `number==1000`, you check 499 numbers with `i<=1000/2`, but just 30 with `i*i <= 1000`.

Comment: +1 the idea is really cool!
But edited the code and got `time limit exceeded`. I really appreciate this answer because it's good and makes the program faster but still have problem with time limit ;/